# show_path in Rails table not using right :id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, routes

Rails newbie here, writing a sample app that has the following three models and relationships:

Sales person:

```
   class Salesperson < ActiveRecord::Base
       has_many :clients
```

Client:

```
   class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
       has_many :orders
       belongs_to: salesperson
```

Orders:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :client
```

On the page clients/show.html.erb I have a partial that renders the following:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Total Orders</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

<% @salesperson.clients.each do |client| %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= client.full_name %></td>
        <td><%= client.orders.count %></td>
        <td><%= client.email %></td>
            <td><%= link_to 'View Client', client_path %></td>  
    </tr>

<% end %>   
</table>
```

Resources are all nested, and the page seems to work except for one thing:

Everything is dynamic but the client path: the client name, orders, emails are all displayed for the salesperson, but the view client link seems to always point at a clients/:id link where :id is the salesperson id but not the client ID.

E.g. because the salesperson :id is 1, all the client paths will point to clients/1 down the whole table.

How do I make the client link route correct and dynamic like the rest of the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with

```
<td><%= link_to 'View Client', client_path(client) %></td>
```

or simpler

```
<td><%= link_to 'View Client', client %></td>
```

`client_path` need a parameter that is a `Client` or an id.